# How can I extract my large image dataset from Google Drive to Colab?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, deep-learning, dataset, google-colaboratory

my dataset is in my google drive and need to extract it in Colab to run my code.but it cant extract

I tried unrar for dataset in Colab but still my file are not complete  and miss some of them ,and unzip didnt wok too. Also I did twice to extract but my file are not complete yet . can I extract again ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.